AOT-Runtime error when publishing ASP.NET Core Web API along with Blazor WASM using AOT compilation
I created a Web API project alongside a Blazor WebAssembly project in ASP.NET Core (.NET 8).
The problem is I want to use ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation for the Blazor WebAssembly project but unfortunately when I publish in release mode, the Blazor WebAssembly application fails to start the platform because it doesn't receive the necessary AOT modules.
All I can say about this error is that I encountered the same issue when I published the Blazor WebAssembly application in release mode (using AOT as well) and tried to run it using IIS Express. When I used dotnet-serve it worked fine. I suspect that all is because some files regarding aot-runtime have to be served for the Blazor WebAssembly application to run properly but that is just speculation on my side.
I'd be happy for someone to help me out with this issue. To make things as clear as possible, I will share some snippets below.
Web API Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher<User>, UserPasswordHasher>();
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<User>().AddUserStore<UserStore>().AddApiEndpoints();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapIdentityApi<User>();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseRouting();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();

WebAPI.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Geralt" Version="3.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="8.0.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="8.0.10"/>
        <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\WebApp\WebApp.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>

WebApp.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
        <RunAOTCompilation>true</RunAOTCompilation>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="8.0.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="8.0.10" PrivateAssets="all" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Edit: I was using a publishing profile, using dotnet publish solved this issue for me.

could you please share which command you have used to publish the application and from which directory you are publishing? could you share the repressible steps for the error? here is the document you could refer for more detail https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-build-tools-and-aot?view=aspnetcore-8.0

@JalpaPanchal sure, I will add those things in a bit. I do feel compelled to ask if this works for you? Or at least, if you think it should? Because it would be somewhat helpful to know if either is the case, especially if it is the case that this works for you.

I have used Blazor WebAssembly project which i have created with "ASP.NET Core Hosted" and used this  dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish  command to publish the project from the solution root directory in my case i did not got any error while i run this command or after hosting the published project on the iis server. let me know if the mentioned steps are different from yours.

@JalpaPanchal Solved this before reading your last comment because your initial comment was already on point enough to push me into the right direction fortunately. You're right, using dotnet publish works but using a regular publishing profile does not. Thank you. ^^

glad it helps i will post the steps. you can share your solution if you think that is right. so that it will help other in future if they face similar issue.

You could use the below command to publish the project. make sure you run from the root folder of the solution directory:
dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish

Here is the official document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-build-tools-and-aot?view=aspnetcore-8.0
